# Jenkins error: Unable to read /home/jenkins/.jenkins/config.xml

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins Problem Statement -

During jenkins restart process getting below error

```
hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad:org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException: java.io.IOException: Unable to read /home/jenkins/.jenkins/config.xml
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:248)
    Caused by: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException:java.io.IOException: Unable to read /home/jenkins/.jenkins/config.xml

    Caused by: jenkins.util.xstream.CriticalXStreamException:   
    hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm : 
    hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm

 ---- Debugging information ----

 message:  hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm
 cause-exception     :      
 com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException

 cause-message       : 
 hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectorySecurityRealm
 class               : hudson.model.Hudson
 required-type       : hudson.model.Hudson
 converter-type      : hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter
 path                : /hudson/securityRealm
 line number         : 550
 version             : not available
 -------------------------------
```

IMPORTANT: Debugging info highlights the issues around - Active Directory / LDAP Plugin

NOTE: Upon disabling (commenting line number 550 on config.xml) Jenkins UP but unable to login to Jenkins.

An issue related online forums referred but no luck

1. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/iQ3iMvfOxQk
2. https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=764711

   [image: Here an screenshot of the Jenkins error]

Comment: Is your Jenkins a linux server or just in your laptop?

Answer (score 1):

First check your JENKINS_HOME environment variable path, and also check

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/jenkins
```

If everything in above step is correct then do the following steps to recover the config.xml

Stop jenkins service

```
service jenkins stop
```

Move JENKINS_HOME/config.xml to another file for backup

```
mv JENKINS_HOME/config.xml JENKINS_HOME/config.xml_bak
```

Start jenkins service

```
service jenkins start
```

Comment: and what if that file is missing for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

This issue generally occurs when there is a cyclic dependency of the plugins and the version's are not the supported one

Since it is related to LDAP try modifying the security tag to false instead of true and then re start the Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and all I did was just set the env variable `JENKINS_HOME=C:\jenkins` and that fixed the issue for me.